# How can I split an array into smaller arrays?

Tags: c#

I want to take a list of names, add them to an array, then split that array into N groups, then display those arrays in separate textboxes in a Windows form. So far I have this, which takes the list and splits them up, but honestly, I don't think it's doing what I want it to do.

MasterList:

Johnny, Mark, Tom, Carl, Jenny, Susie, Ben, Tim, Angie

Group 1: Johnny, Mark, Angie

Group 2: Tom, Carl

Group 3: Jenny, Susie

Group 4: Ben, Tim

```
void addnamestoList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.studentnameTboxContent))
    {
        int num = (int)MessageBox.Show("No content to format.", 
                  "Message", 
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                  MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else
    {
        transformText();
    }
}

public void transformText()
{
    string[] masterList = studentnameTboxContent.Split('\n');
    var split = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, masterList.Length)
        group masterList[index] by index / int.Parse(groupcountTboxContent);

    studentNames.Text = "";
    foreach (var Array in split)
    {
        studentNames.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Array.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Method to randomize list:

```
private string[] randomizeList(string[] list)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string[] randomList = list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

            return randomList;
        }
```

Comment: what are you grouping them by? E.g., can you outline a short sample of the source and a short sample of how the list should be grouped? It's not too clear from the sample provided

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: That helps. How are you deciding which name goes into which group?

Comment: It's completely random. I added the method I'm calling on masterList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, but it isn't very elegant. Basically calculate the group size based on the group count entered by the user, determine how many items should be in each group, and determine the number of remaining items that need to be added to the first lists (if the group cannot be evenly divided by the count).

Then, in a loop, skip the number of items you've taken so far, then take the group size number of items, and if there are still extra items that need to be added, grab them from the end of the list:

```
var masterList = new List<string>
{
    "Johnny", "Mark", "Tom", "Carl",
    "Jenny", "Susie", "Ben", "Tim", "Angie"            
};

var groupCount = 4; // Entered by the user

var minGroupSize = masterList.Count / groupCount;
var extraItems = masterList.Count % groupCount;

var groupedNames = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
{
    groupedNames.Add(masterList.Skip(i * minGroupSize).Take(minGroupSize).ToList());

    if (i < extraItems)
    {
        groupedNames[i].Add(masterList[masterList.Count - 1 - i]);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Here are the groups:");
for(int index = 0; index < groupedNames.Count; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"#{index + 1}: {string.Join(", ", groupedNames[index])}");
}

Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

[image]

---

This code can easily be extracted into a method so it can be re-used elsewhere:

```
static List<List<string>> GetGroups(List<string> masterList, int groupCount)
{
    var groups = new List<List<string>>();

    // Argument validation. All of these conditions should be true.
    if (masterList != null && groupCount > 0 && groupCount <= masterList.Count)
    {
        var minGroupSize = masterList.Count / groupCount;
        var extraItems = masterList.Count % groupCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
        {
            groups.Add(masterList.Skip(i * minGroupSize).Take(minGroupSize).ToList());

            if (i < extraItems)
            {
                groups[i].Add(masterList[masterList.Count - 1 - i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var masterList = new List<string>
{
    "Johnny", "Mark", "Tom", "Carl", "Jenny",
    "Susie", "Ben", "Tim", "Angie"
};

var groupedNames = GetGroups(masterList, 4);
```

Comment: So groupedNames would contain the list broken into N groups. How could I then print these groups off in a textbox? How could I call them via an index?

Comment: Each "group" is a `List<string>`. I showed one way to output them in my example using `string.Join` (which you are also using in your example). And you can use indexes just like an array, using square brackets (which I also do in my example). Does it not work with your existing `foreach` code? I don't understand which part is not working for you.